# Flutter reduce padding of text in SleekCircularSlider

Tags: flutter

flutter reduces padding SleekCircularSlider and text. It's sowing too much space between bar and text.

my code

```
        SleekCircularSlider(
          min: 0,
          max: 120.0,
          initialValue: 60,
          appearance: CircularSliderAppearance(
              startAngle: 110,
              angleRange: 70,
              animationEnabled: true,
              infoProperties: InfoProperties(
                bottomLabelText: 'kg',
                bottomLabelStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                ),
                mainLabelStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25,
                  fontFamily: 'RalewaySemiBold',
                ),
                modifier: (double value) {
                  final roundedValue = value.ceil().toInt().toString();
                  return '$roundedValue ';
                },
              ),
              customColors: CustomSliderColors(
                hideShadow: true,
                trackColor: Color(0xffCFE7FB),
                dotColor: Color(0XFFFAFAFA),
                progressBarColor: kPrimaryColor,
              ),
              customWidths: CustomSliderWidths(
                trackWidth: 4,
                progressBarWidth: 12,
                handlerSize: 3,
              )
          ),
          onChangeEnd: (double weight){
            return weight;
          },
        ),
```

Look like this

[image]

I need to reduce the gap between bar and text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `size` parameter on the `CircularSliderAppearance` to control how much width and height is allotted to your `SleekCircularSlider` widget.

For example, I added,

```
appearance: CircularSliderAppearance(
  size: 100, // Added this
  startAngle: 110,
```

and the output is this,

[image]

Play around and check what `size` suits you best. :)